# Launch locationManager on suspend in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, locationmanager

I searched for solutions for many days, but I didn't find any that satisfied me.

I have launched `LocationManager`, and that is working correctly. Now, I would like to connect `LocationManager` with a schedule. For example, between 9am and 1pm the location manager should be working, after 1pm to 3pm should be off, and then till midnight location manager must be on.

How can I trigger an action when the app is suspended and `LocationManager` is off?

I wrote something like this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(doInBackground:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void) doInBackground:(NSTimer*)time {
    ScheduleModel *schMod = [[ScheduleModel alloc]init];
    if(![schMod isScheduleActiveNow]){
        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        NSLog(@"LocationManager OFF");
    } else if(!locationManager){
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        NSLog(@"LocationManager ON");
    }
    [schMod release];
}
```

But it only works when `LocationManager` is working. When I switch `LocationManager` off, it looks like nothing can trigger action `doInBackground`.

Is there any solution for that problem?

Comment: unfortunately, I realized that this solution works only in simulator, when I install app in device, it's not working at all. I will try to do something similiar with threads. Every help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is suspended, if you have not registered for background location services and started a location manager instance updating, there is no way to have the app start updating again by a timer.
Your options are:

1. Leave the location manager updating, but only respond to the events at the times you intend to be active.
2. Change to significant location change updates only, when entering background state. The app will wake on a significant location change, you can then check the time and respond by starting continuous updates as needed.
3. Set a region monitored, wake on exit the region and respond accordingly.

Continuous updates in background, if not essential, is not a responsible disposition of the users battery. If you explain more of what you are trying to accomplish, I might have better suggestions.

You can see some of what I did to work in the background state in my handler here on github:

[TTLocationHandler](https://github.com/dsdavids/TTLocationHandler)

Answer (score 0):

For implementing a functionality like this you must be take care of some points regarding the state of an ios application and its multitasking capability.
  First thing is that you need to register the app for getting the location updates even if the app is not running.By the significant location changes property you can track the location irrelevent of the app states.
  Another thing is that you need the location updates in particular intervals of time.I think it could be possible by firing a local notification service.